# Implementing tearDownClass functionality in Python 2.6

Tags: python, selenium, nosetests, teardown

I've implemented a "global" `setUp()` for multiple tests inside my class.

Now I would like to know how to make a "global" `teardown()` function which will be run after the last test has finished, similar to `tearDownClass()` in Python > 2.7

If the information helps: I'm using nosetests.

Comment: Why doesn't `tearDownClass()` work for you? Are you using Python 2.6?

Comment: Yes, I'm using Python 2.6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about using [`unittest2`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/unittest2)?

> unittest2 is a backport of the new features added to the unittest testing framework in Python 2.7. It is tested to run on Python 2.4 - 2.7.
>
> ...
>
> New features include:
>
> - class and module level fixtures: setUpClass, **tearDownClass**, setUpModule, tearDownModule